# Loading illusion. Writing on the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make part of a programt that it would look like it's loading in outcome. Something like:

```
Installing....
```

And more dots appears after word Instaling. And at the end of result would look like:

```
Instaling.......... [DONE]
```

I've tryed something like this but it's not working as I want to. Program just takes more time to write a line and it writes everything at once.

```
import time  
print("Installing...", end="")  
time.sleep(2)  
print(".", end="")  
time.sleep(2)  
print(".")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the line isn't flushed to the termianl until the end. You can manually flush it:

```
import sys   # <-

print("Installing...", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()   # <-
```

Or:

```
print("Installing...", end="", flush=True)
```